# int cannot be dereferenced, convert an int value from an array to a string

Tags: java, arrays, int, tostring

I am writing a program to print out the scores of a bowling game. The scores are provided in an int array called rolls:

```
rolls = new int[] {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 6, 3, 2, 7, 1, 8, 0, 9, 0, 0};
```

I am converting the score values to strings in order to print them out because some of the values, like 10 which represents a strike, need to be printed out as strings, like "X" for a value of 10. I am trying to convert the ints to strings and do not know how to fix the error thats occurring, "int cannot be dereferenced." I don't have a lot of experience programming so straightforward answers will be most helpful to me at this point.

```
public class Bowling {
    private int frames;
    private int[] rolls;
    int currentFrameCount=0;
    int currentFrame=1;
    int grantTotal=0;
    int ballCount=1;

public Bowling(int[] rolls, int frames)
{
   this.frames=frames;
   this.rolls=rolls;
}

public void play()
{
    String box1="";
    String box2="";
    String box3="";
    int totalScore = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < rolls.length; i += 2)
    {
        totalScore += rolls[i] + rolls[i+1];

        if(rolls.length % 2 == 0)
        {
            printNormalFrame(rolls[i].toString(), rolls[i+1].toString(), *totalScore.toString());***-->having the error here**
        }

        else
        {
            printBiggerFrame(rolls[i].toString(), rolls[i+1].toString(), totalScore.toString());
        }

    }
}

public void printNormalFrame(String box1, String box2, String totalScore)
{

   System.out.println("+---+---+");
   System.out.println("| " + box1 + " | " + box2 + " |");
   System.out.println("|---+---|");
   System.out.println("|       " + totalScore + " |"); //todo do the padding correctly using String.Format(...), 
   System.out.println("+---+---+");
}

public void printBiggerFrame(String box1, String box2, String box3, int totalScore)
{
    {
        System.out.println("+---+---+---+");
        System.out.println("| " + box1 + " | " + box2 + " | " + box3 + " |");
        System.out.println("|---+---+---|");
        System.out.println("|      "+totalScore+"|"); //todo the padding     correctly using String.Format(...)
        System.out.println("+---+---+---+");
    }
```

Comment: What do you think `totalScore.toString()` should do? Why do you think so? What did you find when you looked up the error message the compiler is giving you?

Comment: I thought that using totalScore.toString() would take the int value of my totalScore and convert it to a string so that I can print it out in the manner that I want to. I looked up the error and found comments about using toString to convert an int to a string, which is what I tried, and something about concatination with " " that I didn't understand. I don't know if I should try something like this: System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));  by importing the util.Arrays package or what.

Answer (score 4):

`int` is a primitive type, so it has no methods for working with. Try

```
1. String.valueOf(rolls[i])
2. Integer.toString(rolls[i])
3. rolls[i] + ""
4. new Integer(rolls[i]).toString()
```

instead of

```
rolls[i].toString()
```

Comment: I would discourage the use of #3 and #4.

Comment: That did the trick! I assume that String.valueOf(rolls[i]); is taking the value of  the array at i and then converting it to a String, is that correct?

Comment: @Liz `String.valueOf()` is overloaded. In this case, it's using the `String.valueOf(int)`, which will convert the `int` value to a `String`. To clarify, the array lookup is not done by `valueOf()`, but by the expression `rolls[i]`, which then passes the single value to the `valueOf()` method.

Comment: @Andreas, yes, I too, but 4-th way looks not better. OP should know all those ways

Comment: @Andreas, that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Sure, and you got my upvote for listing all ways, but not all ways are built equal, and guiding newbie programmers is as much about guiding them away from evil . ;-)

Answer (score 3):

When you call `rolls[i].toString()` you are really calling `.toString()` on an int. Since that method doesn't exist on `int`, it throws an error.

Possible solutions are to just pass the `int` directly to your printing methods. Since these are integers, converting to a `String` isn't going to format it any differently. Another solution would be to use `String.valueOf(rolls[i])` to convert your `int` to a `String`.